# Postgres: select using column as regex, when only some rows are valid regexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

#### TLDR

How to do a regex-match query with a column value (`'input' ~ t.somecolumn`), where just a known subset of rows has a valid regex in that column?

#### Full example

- there is a `blocked_items` table including two varchar columns: `type` and `value`,
- one of the types is `DOMAIN_REGEX`, and then the `value` always includes a correct regex,
- but: for other types `value` doesn't need to be a regex and can cause errors when treated as one.

To check if a domain is blocked, I'm calling this query and passing the URL in question as `$1` parameter:

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM blocked_items WHERE type = 'DOMAIN_REGEX' AND $1 ~ value LIMIT 1
```

The problem: *on some database instances* the query fails if rows with another `type` have `value` that's not a valid regex. On one database this query runs correctly, and on another instance, regardless of the input, throws: `invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`.

Example test data:

```
| type         | value               |
|--------------+---------------------|
| EMAIL        | test+++1@test.com   |
| DOMAIN_REGEX | test\d\.com         |
```

#### Question

I know the reason for my error is that the db engine can choose to check the second condition (`$1 ~ value`) first -- I've checked the `EXPLAIN` for my query and indeed it's different on these two database instances.

Is there a way I can

- force the db to check the `type` column first, so the regex filter is always valid?
- form the query differently to ignore the error for non-regex `value` entries? Or check if it's a valid regex first?
- work around this issue in another way?

// I know changing the schema or using `LIKE` instead will probably suffice, but now that I stumbled upon this I'm curious if there is a solution using regexes like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the schema is not great. If you still *really* have to keep the schema, you could try CASE/WHEN, https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-case/

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to force the order of operations using `case`:

```
SELECT 1
FROM blocked_items
WHERE (CASE WHEN type <> 'DOMAIN_REGEX' THEN false
            ELSE $1 ~ value
       END)
LIMIT 1;
```

In general, SQL (and Postgres) provide little control over the order of evaluation of expressions.  However, `CASE` should provide that control under many circumstances.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept @dssjoblom's anwer since he was first and it looks like they need the points more than you do ;)